# Finding all submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Finding all submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathbb{Z}}$

I know that a subset $A$ of $M$ is a submodule of $R-$module $M$ if:

- $0_{M} \in A$
- $\forall x,y \in A; x+y \in A$
- $\forall x \in A, \forall r \in R; xr \in A$

In this case, with $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Z}$, is that any submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ has form $n \mathbb{Z}$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I assume that $M_R$ means that $M$ is a $R$-module so that $\mathbb{Z}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ means $\mathbb{Z}$ seen like a $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **right**. In fact, one can make the following:

> **Observation.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, then $R$ is a (left) $R$-module and the sub-$R$-modules of $R$ are exactly its ideals.

In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, its ideals are its subgroups, namely the $n\mathbb{Z}$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's my pleasure, you are welcome!

Comment: What the difference between a `left` and a `right` $R$-module if $R$ is commutative?

Comment: @Bernard None, I don't know why I wrote that. Maybe I like scalar multiplication to be on the left.

Comment: Maybe if $R$ is a ring with unity (that may not be commutative) then the left (resp. right) $R$-submodules are the left  (resp. right) ideals?

Comment: @DarthGeek No, cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371129/are-there-different-left-and-right-ideals-in-a-ring-without-identity). And in fact, it has nothing to do with the multiplicative identity of $R$.